# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't load

Tags: 12.10, hibernate, boot-repair

I have a problem with Ubuntu on my laptop. My laptop went into hibernation, but I couldn't log back on, I had to unplug my laptop to restart Ubuntu. My boot menu loads normally and shows Ubuntu and previously installed Windows 7.
I try to run Ubuntu, but it doesn't load, it shows the Ubuntu pic, but then it goes black and doesn't reach the login page.

I tried using a live CD and used the Boot Repair software, I tried loading Ubuntu, but it still didn't load. This is the link the repair gave me:

[Boot-Info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5724955/)

I was wondering someone could help me out, I don't have great knowledge about Ubuntu, but it seems a bit strange it suddenly won't load, this is the first time I had a problem?

Comment: Have you tried booting in the Recovery Mode?

Comment: yes, I ran recovery, then normal boot from recovery menu, same result.

Answer (score -1):

if you are need to use ubuntu eargently then plug in your your bootable usb and completley reinstall ubuntu

if you want to keep everything the way things are then simply wait till there is an upgrade or downgrade and downgrade/upgrade the system.

Comment: I don't have a problem reinstalling ubuntu, but there is some data there I would like to get first. I tried using the live CD, but the home folder was empty. Any ideas??

Comment: the Home folder of the liveCD is empty, that's normal. The Home folder you need is the one inside your sda5 partition. Is it empty too?